# Image change depending to dropdown value change?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Templating Example of select2 library. When first time I change dropdown value it works and preview correct image, but second time, it appends second image and do not place first image.

Js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('select#event_palette').change(function () {
       var selectVal = 'res/img/Palette/' + $(this).val() + '-md.jpg';
       $("#app-bg").append("<img src='"+ selectVal + "'></img>");
     //  $("#app-bg").remove();
   });
});
```

Comment: Just to make it clear, you want to "replace" the image not "add" another one, right?

Comment: @Zahema value change to image add code is proper but i have not idea second image to replace  first image.

Answer (score 2):

You are appending new image to same node replace it to make it work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('select#event_palette').change(function () {
       var selectVal = 'res/img/Palette/' + $(this).val() + '-md.jpg';
       $("#app-bg").html("<img src='"+ selectVal + "'></img>");
   });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Problem is resloved.

Answer (score 0):

use html() instead of append().

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
     $('select#event_palette').change(function () {
       var selectVal = 'res/img/Palette/' + $(this).val() + '-md.jpg';
       $("#app-bg").html("<img src='"+ selectVal + "'></img>");
   });
  });
```